# How to say "reducing the chance" fluently in this case?

Tags: sentence-choice

My friend said he was bitten by mosquitos on twitter, since any mosquito has the limited quota of sucking blood, my friend reduced the probability of me being bitten, and I want to reply him that as a small joke.

How could I say it naturally and fluently?(the humorer the better.)

> "You reduced the probability of me being bitten."

is what I came up with, but I feel it's a bit awkward sounding(or it's in reality pretty fluent?), is there any better way to say it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"reduced the probability" is rather formal and technical.

The colloquial equivalent is "cut the chance"

> Great! You've cut the chance of me being bitten!

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence

> You *reduced the probability* of me being bitten.

is correct, but sounds very mathematical, otherwise you might say

> You reduced the *chances* of me being bitten.

However, if you wanted to say it as a mathematical joke, you might say

> You reduced the *maximum likelihood* of me being bitten.
>   You shifted the *probability distribution* of me being bitten to the left.
>   You changed the *posterior predictive distribution* of me being bitten.

Of course there is always

> Better you than me *(mate)*!

or simply

> Thank you, I appreciate it!